# Excplicit id values using EF Code-first and migrations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I develop my ASP.NET MVC4 app using EF Code-first, also im using Migrations feature. I have specific entity and i want to set explicit id values for some reasons. How can i do this? I tried to mark id property with attribute like this:

```
public class NewsSource
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string WebSiteUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Then i add corresponding migration, delete database and try to update database using Seed() method like this:

```
context.NewsSources.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Title,
            new NewsSource {Id = 654, Title = "ABC", WebSiteUrl = @"http://www.abc.com/"},
            new NewsSource {Id = 22, Title = "XYZ", WebSiteUrl = @"http://XYZ.ru/"});
```

And ive got this error: "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'NewsSources' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF". How can i set identity_insert to ON using EF and migrations. As i understood from many topics its impossible and i have to use direct SQL-commands. Am i wrong?

Comment: I think you're not wrong. As long you're putting the `[Key]` annotation, EF will want to handle that ID by it-self. Maybe you should consider another structure for your table.
I may have wrong, but my research gave me the same result as yours : it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem when I tried to change a column to an IDENTITY field when it was originally not an identity field. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15679917/150342) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348/150342). You have to remove the column and recreate it to [remove IDENTITY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8230300/150342) so fixing up foreign keys etc is probably a step too far for Entity Framework to do in a migration. You will have to alter the Up() and Down() methods yourself, or you may get away with doing it in the database.

Comment: I just got bitten by this as well... 
  DropColumn("Customer", "CustomerId");
  AddColumn("Customer", "CustomerId", c => c.Long(nullable: false, identity: false));
solved it!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove the DatabaseGenerated attribute and just leave the [Key] attribute?

```
public class NewsSource
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string WebSiteUrl { get; set; }
}
```

I ran into this issue awhile back and I believe this was a work around for me. I can't test it now since I don't have any projects in front of me with EF in them. All I can say is EF code first and the nuget migrations package is a great thing, if you treat it the way you are supposed to treat it. I have gotten myself into a number of WTF moments when using the two together and trying to seed complex related models.  Good luck!