# Insert the same Guid key in two different tables in two databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have two tables APP in two databases, I want to get the same App identifier in the two databases, but when I insert the app into the first database and insert it in the second database I have either a new Guid generated (if I specify a default value in my column) or a null guid.

here's my code of inserting the app in the two tables of the databases:

```
 app.Id_App = Guid.NewGuid();
            app.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
            app.PublisherId_advertiserPublisher = id_publisher;
            db.AppSet.AddObject(app);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //add app to db2


            App2 appDB2 = new App2()
            {
                App_link=app.App_link,
                Id_app= app.Id_App,                   
                CategoryId_cat=app.CategoryId_cat,
                Description=app.Description,
                keywords=keywords.Key_word,             
            };
       DB2.App.AddObject(appDB2);
            pushDB.SaveChanges();
```

I've already turned `rowGuid` in table definition to no.
have I missed something? is there a better way to get the same guid key in two different databases?
thanks.

Comment: Please show the entity declarations (class App and App2).

Comment: `Guid` is not some magic type that behaves differently from all other types. If your model doesn't have any special information about a `uniqueidentifier` column, it's updateable by doing exactly what you're doing now. I'm pretty sure your model does have some special information that says the column is server-calculated. Get rid of that. Where to look for that special information depends on how your model is constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you originally specified that `Id_app` should be database generated, then changed it to `DatabaseGenerated.None`, entity framework does not issue sql to alter the underlying table. You will need to drop and re-create the table or manually alter it in the database or create a custom migration.

References:

[Drop identity using entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348/150342)

[Switch IDENTITY on/off with custom migration](http://romiller.com/2013/04/30/ef6-switching-identity-onoff-with-a-custom-migration-operation/)

[Migrations: does not detect changes to DatabaseGeneratedOption](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/509) - you can vote for it in a future version here

Comment: you are right, I've changed it from Identity to none, but I didn't have to recreate the table, I changed it in the xml of the entity framework and the database, thank you for your help, it works.