# DatabaseGeneratedOption.None not working in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to manually enter primary key values in a database, as i need the key values to be in sync with an Enum.  However using DatabaseGeneratedoption.None doesn't appear to work. Even when i delete the database and start fresh, the Id column in the JobType still has an auto-incrmeneting primary key.

Is it anything to do with the fact that i'm using an enum as a primary key?

Job Entity

```
public class Job : EntityBase
{
    public long JobId { get; set; }       
    public JobTypeEnum JobTypeId { get; set; }
    public JobType JobType { get; set; }      
}
```

Job Type

```
public class JobType 
{         
    public JobTypeEnum Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }       
}
```

Configuration Classes

```
public class JobTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<JobType>
{
    public JobTypeConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        Property(x => x.Name).HasMaxLength(20);
        Property(x => x.Description).HasMaxLength(255);
    }
}

public class JobConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Job>
{
    public JobConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.JobId);
        Property(x => x.JobId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);          
         HasRequired(x => x.JobType).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.JobTypeId);

    }
}
```

Model Builder

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new JobConfiguration());
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new JobTypeConfiguration());
```

**EDIT:**

I've tracked down a probable cause. I have a Migration that creates tables for Elmah. If i exclude that migration, then it works fine. If i include it, then it doesn't.

Bizarre...

Answer (score 2):

I have taken your code and added it to my project. This is the Migration code generated:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Jobs",
            c => new
                {
                    JobId = c.Long(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    JobTypeId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.JobId)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.JobTypes", t => t.JobTypeId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.JobTypeId);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.JobTypes",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Name = c.String(maxLength: 20),
                    Description = c.String(maxLength: 255),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);


    }
```

You can see that the `dbo.JobTypes` table does not have identity: true. You may find that you have fallen into the problem described here: [How to alter column from DatabaseGenerated.Identity to DatabaseGenerated.None](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348/150342)

The simplest thing to do is probably to find the `CreateTable` statement for `JobType`, fix it, then re-create the database.

Comment: Cheers, but as said in OP, this happens when i delete and recreate the database too.

Comment: Can you post the `CreateTable` statement from your Up Migration? Is there an `ALTER TABLE` statement in a subsequent migration?

Comment: I'm using automatic migrations at the moment.

Comment: Think i've tracked down the problem. Updated the question but it's probably not of any use to anyone... Thanks for the help.