# ASP.NET MVC 6 - Assigning NOT NULL to the Primary Key in Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Code:

```
migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey("AspNetRoles", "PK_AspNetRoles", new[] { "Id" }, isClustered: true);
```

I am getting the error message as `Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'AspNetRoles'.`

Namespace of MigrationBuilder - `Microsoft.Data.Entity.Relational.Migrations.Builders`

How to assign `NOT NULL` to the above code in *ASP.NET MVC 6*

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the code-first approach?

Comment: Yes, this is code first approach. I am following from [this](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc#efm) article

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907411/entering-keys-manually-with-entity-framework?

Comment: You need the Required attribute on Id in your AspNetRoles class.

Comment: Can you show us your POCO class too?

Comment: I tried with adding data annotation `[Key, Required]` for `id` column. The issue remains the same. I am following exactly from [this](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/vc#efm) article.

Comment: Attributes won't work yet in EF7. What is the property type of Id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a **very temporary** workaround to be able to write some code-first EF entities and advance, I commented out the part of the migration script dealing with those keys.

Obviously this butchers the relations in the ASP.NET users and roles tables and isn't a workable long term solution, I assume it will be fixed or someone will find a real solution at some point.

Some of the lines I commented out (I got the same error with Users once I changed Roles).

```
        //migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey("AspNetRoles", "PK_AspNetRoles", new[] { "Id" }, isClustered: true);

        //migrationBuilder.AddPrimaryKey("AspNetUsers", "PK_AspNetUsers", new[] { "Id" }, isClustered: true);
        ....
        //migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        //    "AspNetRoleClaims",
        //    "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
        //    new[] { "RoleId" },
        //    "AspNetRoles",
        //    new[] { "Id" },
        //    cascadeDelete: false);

        //migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        //    "AspNetUserClaims",
        //    "FK_AspNetUserClaims_AspNetUsers_UserId",
        //    new[] { "UserId" },
        //    "AspNetUsers",
        //    new[] { "Id" },
        //    cascadeDelete: false);

        //migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        //    "AspNetUserLogins",
        //    "FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId",
        //    new[] { "UserId" },
        //    "AspNetUsers",
        //    new[] { "Id" },
        //    cascadeDelete: false);
        ...
        //migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey("AspNetRoleClaims", "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId");

        //migrationBuilder.DropPrimaryKey("AspNetRoles", "PK_AspNetRoles");

        //migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        //    "AspNetRoleClaims",
        //    "FK_AspNetRoleClaims_AspNetRoles_RoleId",
        //    new[] { "RoleId" },
        //    "AspNetRoles",
        //    new[] { "Id" },
        //    cascadeDelete: false);

        //migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
        //    "AspNetUserLogins",
        //    "FK_AspNetUserLogins_AspNetUsers_UserId",
        //    new[] { "UserId" },
        //    "AspNetUsers",
        //    new[] { "Id" },
        //    cascadeDelete: false);
```

This is presumably a bug or missing feature in the very early build of EF7?