# Creating Entity Framework Table That Does Not Have Auto Increment Id

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Using Entity Framework SQL-Server-CE I have created a table like this:

```
class Era {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [Index(IsUnique=true), Required]
    public long Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long StartDate { get; set; }
    public long EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I try to insert into it using Entity Framework, the `Id` field of the `Era` object is ignored and an auto incremented `Id` is inserted.

How can I make the `Id` field not to use the auto incremented value, and use the given value instead, using annotations preferably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this is the answer that i was looking for:

if you want to have a table with non-auto increment id in entity framework; you need to first backup the data, drop the table(this can be done by commenting the relevant `DbSet` in your `DbContext` class), adding the annotation `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` then migrating and updating database.

Comment: Your root problem is that the column is IDENTITY when it should be `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`. You have found an interesting workaround, but really you should change the column. You are correct about needing to do more than add a data annotation if you have already created the table....http://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348

Answer (score 6):

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

This ensures that EF will not try and change the values and will simply insert them with the rest of the data.

here is detail description about it [link](http://blog.robertobonini.com/2014/10/09/entity-framework-with-identity-insert/)

Comment: The link is about switching identity insert on. You don't need to do that if you create a primary key that is not database generated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

The default is that the database generates a value, so you need to explicitly turn that off.

Comment: adding that annotation and trying to insert results in this exception:
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = Id ]

Comment: @raven  as I mention see this link  http://blog.robertobonini.com/2014/10/09/entity-framework-with-identity-insert/

Comment: @raven After adding that annotation you must recreate the database

Comment: @sm.abdullah i'm trying that out right now, but in that example an sql connection string is required, but i'm using sql compact and i have no idea what to use there.

Comment: @ErikEJ yes i have updated the database using package manager console

Comment: @raven updating the database does not necessarily drop and re-create the table or the database http://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348

Comment: @Colin i did not know that. are you saying that if you recreate the table you wont need to do the stuff i've done in my answer?

Comment: Yes, and that is why @ErikEJ said you should recreate the database. If the table is empty that's not a problem. If you need to fix up data you could use a custom migration: http://romiller.com/2013/04/30/ef6-switching-identity-onoff-with-a-custom-migration-operation/