# Making table primary key auto incremented Entity Framework 7 does not work

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int AdminID { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Passwort { get; set; }
public DateTime ErstelltAm { get; set; }
```

The table is constructed almost correct but the primary key is not auto incremented. How do i fix this?

Comment: `[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int AdminID{ get; set; }`

Comment: Sorry but that did not help. Same result as before.

Comment: I looked it up and it tinka's solution should work in EF5. Is it maybe a EF7 problem?

Comment: This can happen (in EF6 - don't know about EF7) if the table was originally created with `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` and you are trying to change it. You could try dropping and recreating the table http://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348/150342

Comment: I already tried to drop the whole DB, deleting the migrations and snapshot file and starting over. Still when I make my DB from code it is not auto incremented.

Answer (score 1):

If your table is named admin, AdminId will become an IDENTITY primary key. If that is not the case, you must configure in your DbContext class:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MeineTabelle>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Key(e => e.AdminID);
        });
    }
```

Comment: That is how it was in EF6 and before but in EF7 the primary key is not auto increment by default and I don’t know how to activate it other than in my original post.

Comment: @Sknecht is it not working for you, it should work i also found this only solution on internet

Comment: Making AdminID the primary key is not my problem my problem is that it is not auto incremented by default and I don’t get it to work to activate it.

Comment: What version of EF7 do you use? IDENTITY only became default in later beta builds

Comment: @ErikEJ I use the 7.0.0-beta5

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the ID property from the entity and update database. Again add it back with Database Generated Option. This solution worked fine in my case.

```
[Table("tblCurrencies")]
public class Currency:DefaultColumns
{
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false), MaxLength(255),Index(IsUnique =true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Alies { get; set; }

    public string DecimalName{ get; set; }

    public double CurrenctRate { get; set; }
}
```