# Configuring an Auto Increment field on an Abstract Class in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, abstract-class, auto-increment, identity

I have some code first entities similar to these:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal {
    public string OtherDogRelatedStuff { get; set; }
}

public class Bird : Animal {
    public string OtherBirdRelatedStuff { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext {

    public IDbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        var pluraliser = PluralizationService.CreateService(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"));

        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("vs");
        modelBuilder.Types().Configure(t => t.ToTable(pluraliser.Pluralize(t.ClrType.Name)));

        // This next line doesn't give ID column IDENTITY(1,1)
        modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>().Property(_ => _.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        // This line puts IDENTITY(1,1) on Animal.ID, but causes errors when I try to add/update data.
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().Property(_ => _.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }        
}
```

And I want table per type... so the tables look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Animals (
    ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    NumberOfLegs INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pkAnimals PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)

CREATE TABLE Dogs (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    OtherDogRelatedStuff VARCHAR(200),
    CONSTRAINT pkDogs PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT fkAnimal_Dog FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Animals(ID)
)

CREATE TABLE Birds (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    OtherBirdRelatedStuff VARCHAR(200),
    CONSTRAINT pkBirds PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT fkAnimal_Bird FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Animals(ID)
)
```

With data looking like this:

```
---Animals----------
ID      NumberOfLegs
1       4
2       4
3       2

---Dogs---------------------
ID      OtherDogRelatedStuff
1       Woof1
2       Woof2

---Birds---------------------
ID      OtherCatRelatedStuff
3       Sqwark1
```

But I can't get the auto increment ID working, or configured correctly.

I've tried this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>().Property(_ => _.ID)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

But because `Animal` is abstract this doesn't seem to set the `IDENTITY(1,1)` property on the table.

I've also tried doing the same on the `Dog` entity, which correctly adds the identity property to the ID column in the `Animals` table, but I get an `UpdateException` when I try to add new entities to the database on the `SaveChanges()` method:

```
A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'ID'.
```

How can I correctly set the ID column on the abstract type to auto increment, and make it work when I add data?

Comment: Link the relevant parts of your dbcontext class please

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: Done.

Comment: Noticed you have `ID` on both animal and dog while `Dog` inherits it from `Animal`

Comment: Ah yes, thats a mistake when I wrote the question. My real class doesn't have ID in the concrete classes. I'll fix it.

Comment: I'll also add a second concrete class to further clarify what my real stucture looks like.

Comment: I think `modelBuilder.Types().Configure(t => t.ToTable(pluraliser.Pluralize(t.ClrType.Name)));` also maps `Animal` to a table which shouldn't happen. You can only map the derived classes to a table

Comment: Doesn't work either. I changed it to this: `modelBuilder.Types().Where(t => t != typeof(Animal)).Configure(t => t.ToTable(pluraliser.Pluralize(t.ClrType.Name)));` but the ID column in the Animals table doesn't get IDENTITY(1,1)

Comment: Then I don't know what's causing your problem I'm afraid, for me this approach always works :/ However I always use `DbSet` instead of `IDbSet` and instead of mapping all types to the table, I do it for every Entity, so like `modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().ToTable("Dogs");`. I don't think that causes the problem, but hey who knows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say use the interface or separate abstract class to put common functionalities like this:

```
public interface Common{
  int ID { get; set; }
}
public class Animal : Common {
[DatabaseGenerated(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]    
public int ID { get; set; }
public int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Common {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string OtherDogRelatedStuff { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this isn't what I want. I want an Animal table with an auto-inc primary key that maps to an abstract type, and 1 or more tables that share the same ID linked by foreign key that inherit Animal.

Comment: Just take the attribute he specified and place it on your Animal Abstract class.

Comment: I've already tried that... it doesn't make any difference if I specify by attribute on the class, or do it in OnModelCreating... same result.

Comment: Actually, adding the `[DatabaseGenerated(...)]` attribute worked... Not sure why it didn't the first time I tried. I don't want the interface though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With these models...

```
public abstract class Animal
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Animal
{
    public string OtherDogRelatedStuff { get; set; }
}

public class Bird : Animal
{
    public string OtherBirdRelatedStuff { get; set; }
}
```

...and this in the context...

```
public IDbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Dog>().ToTable("Dogs");
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bird>().ToTable("Birds");
}
```

...then in the package manager execute `Add-Migration "Animals"`
then `Update-Database -Script`

You should get:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Animals] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [NumberOfLegs] [int] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Animals] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dogs] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OtherDogRelatedStuff] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Dogs] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_ID] ON [dbo].[Dogs]([ID])
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Birds] (
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OtherBirdRelatedStuff] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Birds] PRIMARY KEY ([ID])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_ID] ON [dbo].[Birds]([ID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Dogs] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Dogs_dbo.Animals_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([ID]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[Animals] ([ID])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Birds] 
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Birds_dbo.Animals_ID] FOREIGN KEY ([ID]) 
REFERENCES [dbo].[Animals] ([ID])
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'etc)
```

which is what you want, right?

Reference:
[Inheritance with EF Code First: Part 2 – Table per Type (TPT)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt)

Be aware that sometimes you can run into issues with a field created with an identity if it has been initially created without an identity (and vice versa). You can fix that by dropping and recreating the table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348/150342

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I fixed it using data annotation in the abstract class, like this:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
}
```