# Primary Key Does not autoincrement Entity Framework in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, auto-increment

I have three small model classes and although two of them does works one is not and I can't figure out why. I found several solutions but neither of them helped me. First of all, code first approach was used in the project.

So, the main problem is that the PK in the `Coupon` class is not set to autoincrement value. I refer to the tables from Server Explorer and see PK's properties. Realized that other two classes PK's properties are set as `Is Identity` to `True` and `Identity Increment = 1` whereas in the `Coupon`'s PK's property they are set as `Is Identity` to `False` and `Identity Increment` to 0.

I think the problem is somewhere there and below you can find the small model class I am having trouble with.

```
public class Coupon
{
    public Coupon()
    {
        footballMatches = new List<FootballMatch>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CouponId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual List<FootballMatch> footballMatches { get; set; }
}
```

Ask me more if you need further information.

Thanks !

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but is there any reason you wouldn't use GUIDs instead of integers? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Most probably I am new to c#, nothing special.

Comment: using int is not to uncommon

Comment: Okay I will try to get used to them thanks. Lets focus on my question now haha :)

Comment: Well, if the PK for `Coupon` is set to `Is Identity=false` in the database, then it is **NOT** an identity column and therefore will not auto-increment...... you need to delete that column and re-add it again, this time with the identity spec set to `true`

Comment: That is why there is a code just at top of the CouponId. As you can see, it shall be setting it to the identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not expected that, but I found the solution in such a silly way. The solution to my problem was just re-adding the key. At first, I did not agree with marc_s because I also tried re-adding before. Apparently, I did in a wrong way when I firstly tried re-adding.

What I made wrong is converting `int` to `string` then converting back to `int` while I did not touch the name of the instance, which is CouponId. That *did not* work. However, and sadly, I also had to change the name of the instance as well to make it work. I changed the line `public int CouponId` to `public string CouponName` then convert back to the actual name. Now it shows the expected behaviour.

Briefly, the simple solution is to change the key both variable and name and alter them to their actual names again. That simply.

By the way, while doing them please do not forget to update your migrations between each step. So the workflow is like `Change->Update->Change Back->Update.`

Hope that can help others who went through the same trouble.

Comment: More explanation of what has happened here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348/150342