# Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id' although Id is set

Tags: sql, model-view-controller

I have a strange problem.
I want to insert an item to a table from database. I use Entity Framework.
Although the Id is set, I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'project_atp.dbo.ShoppingCarts'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

[image]

The table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ShoppingCarts] (
[Id]           INT              NOT NULL,
[Guid]         UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NULL,
[Name]         NVARCHAR (255)   NULL,
[Code]         NVARCHAR (255)   NULL,
[SupplierNo]   NVARCHAR (255)   NULL,
[SupplierName] NVARCHAR (255)   NULL,
[Price]        NVARCHAR (50)    NULL,
[Quantity]     INT              NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_ShoppingCarts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
 );
```

Can you please advise what could be wrong here! Thanks!

Comment: My first thought is that field mapping is incorrectly defined for the `Id` column, and it subsequently isn't sent.

Comment: Could you please post your table definitions?

Comment: I've updated the question with the table definition

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem with changing the definition for  Id in database, to: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ShoppingCarts] (
    [Id]           INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,.........

Comment: If you've solved the problem, then feel free to write your own answer to your question, so that if people have a similar problem in the future they might see your own solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[By default Entity Framework assumes that an integer primary key is database generated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18917348/5690722). As the result Entity Framework would not include Primary Key field in the actual `INSERT` statement.

I would try to either play along and `ALTER` the table to auto-generate the ID (which judging by your comment you did)

or set StoreGeneratedPattern property of OnlineCarStore.Models.ShoppingCarts Id column to 'None'

or use [annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/enhancing-data-validation): `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`.