# EF Code First - Identity is always on

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using Code first and my ID column looks like this:

```
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
```

Am trying to cancel the identity of some tables and cannot do it.
I am using Fluent API:

```
.Property(b => b.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

and the generated code is of migration is:

```
     public override void Up()
     {
            AlterColumn("MyEntity", "ID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, 
             identity: false));
     }

     public override void Down()
     {
            AlterColumn("MyEntity", "ID", c => c.Int(nullable: false, 
            identity: true));
    }
```

But it doesn't change in the db.
Any ideas please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entering keys manually with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907411/entering-keys-manually-with-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using data annotations.

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```